# Risk if a registrant picks a username that matches a unix command?

Tags: unix, directory, filenames

In my app I ask users to register using a unique name. The app creates a directory for them with that name that they then can work with, saving files, etc.

I hadn't really thought about screening for other than alpha-numeric for the name. However, I ran across a thread somewhere than said to make sure not to create directory names that match a unix command name.

Is this a legitimate risk? If so, how might one programmatically screen for such an occurrence? I'm also curious how such a scenario might play out to illustrate the problem (exploit?). That last part is academic interest only, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it doesn't matter(has no obvious security risk). Most softwares, for example shell, search a unix command based on some enviroment variables(like PATH). So even if your created directory matches a unix command like "cd", it can only be used as a parameter to other unix command, like **cd cd**.

However, if another application search the unix command based on other approaches like searching some directories, it may lead to security breaches.

Comment: Thanks for answering, makes me feel a little better.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of that being a risk is if you're going to turn around and process those user names through command-line functions.  You would want to be careful to escape the user names anywhere that they could be interpreted as a command...though off the top of my head, with strictly alphanumeric user names, you'd have to go to a lot of trouble to run into such a risk.

If you decided anyway that you wanted to ensure that the username didn't match an application on the path of the creating process, you could shell out from whatever your app environment is, and evaluate the result of `which $prospectiveUsername`.  If it returns anything other than an empty string, you know that the username is an application on the process's path.

**NOTE:** In the above scenario, make sure you sanitize the username **before** calling out to the shell command.  Otherwise, you *do* run security risks, if e.g. the user decides to enter her username as "janedoe; rm -rf /".

Comment: Excellent answer, more complete and kind of along the lines my head was leaning. Thanks.